# C++, how to access with a pointer to a specific address

Tags: c++, pointers

I was curious, so I tried to do this:

First program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a = 5;

int main()
{
    
    cout << "Value of a: " << a << endl;
    cout << "Address of a: " << &a << endl;
    
    system("pause");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

- Value of a: 5
- Address of a: 0x472010

Second program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x472010);
    
int main() 
{   
    cout << "Value of p: " << *p << endl;
    cout << "The address that the pointer points to: " << p << endl;
    
    cout << endl;
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So, I want to read the value of the variable 'a' with
the 'p' pointer belonging to the another program, and the 'p' pointer point to specific address.

everything is fine until i run the second pragram, as the second program doesn't give the desired results

Output second program:

- Value of p: 4661264
- The address that the pointer points to: 0x472010

The result does not change if I keep the window of the first program open.

I promise I’m a beginner and I’m trying new things

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, every time your run your program, the addresses are going to change.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: In the 90`s that kind of thing was possible on 16 bit Windows. As any program could corrupt the memory of another one (or the operating system itself), stability of the system was compromise and it was common to reboot a computer many time a day. Today incorrect code rarely affect other application because a process does not have access to memory of other one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly access another process's memory in the manner you are attempting.  Each process runs in its own address space.  Your 2nd process is trying to access an (invalid) address within its own address space, not within the address space of the 1st process.

On Windows, to read another process's memory, your 2nd process must obtain a `HANDLE` to the 1st process, such as from [`OpenProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess), and then must use [`ReadProcessMemory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) to read memory from an address within the 1st process.

The alternative is for the 1st process to allocate a block of **shared memory** which the 2nd process can access directly.  On Windows, you can use [`CreateFileMapping()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-createfilemappingw) and [`MapViewOfFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) for that purpose (see [Creating Named Shared Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory) on MSDN).  On 'Nix systems, you can use [`shm_open()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) [`mmap()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).